# Is it possible to get Google Analytics data for any website (not my website) using Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is it possible to get Google Analytics data for any website (not my website) using Google Analytics API?

I have created Google API for Google Analytics. Then I am trying to access the Google Analytics data for a different profile id.

It is working for my profile id but not other user's profile id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Analytics API relies on [OAuth 2.0] (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization) for authorization. This simply means that the data extraction module you created needs explicit permission to access a Google Analytics Account. Moreover, the scenario you describe about using a different Profile ID wouldn't work due to the nature in which Accounts and Profiles (Views) are [related] (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618?hl=en) to each other in Google Analytics. So for e.g. if your Google Analytics Account is linked via your email id foo@gmail.com, the profile ID that you use to query must correspond to an actual profile in your Google Analytics account. This is the reason why a random Profile ID wouldn't work.

Comment: I have added the developer email id which we get after making the Google Analytics API to the account for which I need the data. But still, I am not able to get the data. My purpose is that users will enter their blog url on my website and I will get the google analytics of their website. Is this possible?

Comment: Just the website url won't suffice for extracting Google Analytics data, the users have to grant you access to their Google Analytics account. Suggest you have a look at the common OAuth Flows described in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to be granted permission to the account or view to access it.  GA has documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/#concepts)