# Is it possible to get data from my client's website?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm currently creating a new feature in a marketing tool, which should allow my clients to get some metrics of there websites. As far as there is Google-Analytics implemented on their sites.

I have already successfully implemented the [Hello Analytics Example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php). But with that configuration I only get the metrics of my own website.

I found this [Is it possible to get Google Analytics data for any website (not my website) using Google Analytics API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664055/is-it-possible-to-get-google-analytics-data-for-any-website-not-my-website-usi), but this is for version 3 and I'm using version 4 and the links seems to be different between these versions.

If my client need's to authorize my application in there own google-analytics-account, this is usually no problem.

So my questions are:

- Does anyone have a detailed tutorial?
- Did i missed something in the google-api-example?
- Do I need to use an older version of the API?

If you need more informations, just tell me in the comments. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics data is private data.  In order to access private data you must have access to it.   In the case of service accounts you pre authorize the service account by adding the service account email address as a user on the Google Analytics Website.

If you want to be able to access other peoples data you will need to use Oauth2 and authenticate the users requesting their permission.  There is a [Hello Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php) tutorial for PHP on the site.   So in this instance your clients are going to have to authenticate your application and give you access to read their data.

So my questions are:

- Does anyone have a detailed tutorial?

  *yup your looking for the Oauth2 example [Hello Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php)*
- Did i missed something in the google-api-example?

  *Probably not you have access to your own data by adding the service account email sounds like you did it correctly. However you may have miss understood how service accounts work.*
- Do I need to use an older version of the API?

  *Not at all you can use Reporting api v4 or core reporting v3.*

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you, I will go through the Oauth2-example, which seems to be exact what I was looking for. I will come back then.

Comment: Depending upon your relationship with your clients you could ask them to grant you access using the service account email address.   However this can have security issues as you will no be responsible in ensuring that  client 1 does not have access to client 2's data.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you! This was the missing link, which I needed to get the thing working. Perfect!